# Sitemap for breadcrumb and navigation of an MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, navigation, sitemap, breadcrumbs

I am creating an mvc 4 c# web application for an ecommerce site that has both products, categories but also traditional pages.

The site has a global and local navigation, and a breadcrumb.

To assist with managing the navigation, I am considering using a sitemap provider which can be populated and used to drive the navigation and breadcrumb.

Is there any easy way to do such, using a sitemap, custom populated to manager the navigation and breadcumb of the site. An awareness of where the user is on the site can be achieved from the url. Any examples from other solutions as how they achieve such?

Answer (score 7):

Look at the nuget package  mvc sitemap provider. It does that out the box. Tutorial here http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/02/10/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial/

We use it for menus and breadcrumbs for all our MVC sites

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to dynamically generate the sitemap though from database content eg. Products which frequently change. Also needs to support multi language. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can generate sitemap. We use it for country list etc. Look music store tutorial in source code http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dynamic%20sitemaps

Comment: Anything else further you need from me to help with this question?